# is it requited to have MYSQL installed in a pc where i am running tomcat application

Tags: java

I am trying to run an application in my localhost in tomcat, Application has a database .

Now is it required to Install complete MYSQL in that machine or i can just place my sqlDump somewhere in that computer and run my application .

please guide.

Thanks

Comment: If the application requires connection to a running MySQL instance, then you have to either install it or find a running instance with the necessary schema installed.  "sqlDump"?

Comment: The SQL Dump is likely just an exported text file from a mysql database - that does nothing for an application that needs to connect to a mysql instance. You don't have to run a database on your own machine, but there has to be one running somewhere and your software has to be configured to connect to whatever instance it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now is it required to Install complete MYSQL in that machine or i can just place my sqlDump somewhere in that computer and run my application.

No, and no.

You don't have to have MySQL installed on your machine.  It could be installed on another machine that your machine can access via a network connection.

But the sqldump file *does* have to be loaded into a MySQL instance ... somewhere.  I am not aware of any libraries that would allow you to query an sqldump file directly.

(I'm assuming that the dump you are refering to was produced by the standard "mysqldump" utility, and is therefore a text file consisting of SQL DDL and "insert" statements to recreate a database.  Loading such a dump into another vendor's database *might* be possible, though there may be issues with SQL dialects.)

Answer (score 0):

To Run App You Dont require MySql installation even. ALl you need is MySql Jar and Working Connection to M/C, Server where MySql is installed. 
To Access your database (From M/C , Server or localhost(your machine if you have installed MySql in your M/C)) You require to install MySql Software.

Answer (score 0):

If that SQL dump is clean it might be possible to use an embedded pure java database such as HSQL or H2 to load the SQL dump file into. Probably that won't work right away though and the SQL will need to be cleaned up first.

Just to note: I use that technique to load (limited) sql dumps for unit testing purposes so it is certainly possible, just not trivial.